# NestJs - How do I download objects as json files locally?

Tags: json, file, download, nestjs, fs

So I have my NestJs application connected to mongoDB/Mongoose. I'd like to get everything in the repository and save it locally on my computer as a json file. Could anyone advise how to go about that?

backup.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class BackupService {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  private async getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
    return await this.shiftService.getMany();
  }

  public async downloadUserData() {
      const users = await this.getUsers();
      // next step to download as json file to local computer?

  }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write the data to a file using Node's [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module. You'll be able to do something like this:

```js
import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises';
import { join } from 'path';

@Injectable()
export class BackupService {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  private async getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
    return await this.shiftService.getMany();
  }

  public async downloadUserData() {
      const users = await this.getUsers();
      await writeFile(join(process.cwd(), 'db', 'users.json'), JSON.stringify(users));
  }
}
```

This should write the data to a JSON file at `<projectRoot>/db/users.json`. Keep in mind this is a direct write and not an `append`, so any data there will be overwritten.